# parse serialized JSON date

Tags: javascript, json, date

I'm getting dates from a WCF service and I'm getting some inconsistency with the various dates

/Date(-62135578800000-0500)/ -- this returns 00's

vs

/Date(1369188057000-0400)/ -- this works fine

I'm using

```
date = new Date(parseInt(tblData.substr(6)));
```

Any reason the **'0500' is returning "Mon Jan 01 1 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"** 
which seems to be Eastern Standard vs Daylight savings time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just put the numbers in `new Date()` Here: http://jsfiddle.net/4aGyD/1/